# Azure policy - check if there is any budget assigned to the subscription

Tags: azure, azure-policy

How to write azure policy which will audit if subscription has budget assigned. If there are no budget assigned to subscription I want policy to be Non Compliant status.

I've tried to check by using AuditINotExists

```
{
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets"
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
          "details": {
            "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
            "name": "budget"
          }
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the policy code, what you have tried?

Comment: @VenkatV I've updated question with example. I've tried a few more but don't want to include all o them as non of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below policy will audit the **subscription** to check if a budget is assigned to it. If a budget is assigned to the subscription, the subscription will be considered **compliant**, If a budget is not assigned to the subscription, the subscription will be considered **non-compliant**.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets/amount",
          "exists": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Reference:   [Create and manage Azure budgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/tutorial-acm-create-budgets)

Comment: Doesn't work. It results with Compliant state.

Comment: I see at you screen shot that you have Non Compliant Resources - 1. For my subscription it's 0.

Comment: Kindly check with this policy :   {
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Subscription"
},
"then": {
"effect": "auditIfNotExists",
"details": {
"type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
"name": "budget",
"existenceCondition": {
"field": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets/id",
"exists": "true"
}
}
}
},
"parameters": {}
}

Comment: It also doens't work. Why you changed budget/ammount to budget/id? budget/id is not valid property to check.

Comment: If there is no budget assigned to a subscription, the policy you provided should evaluate the subscription as compliant, as the existence condition would not be met since the Microsoft.Consumption/budgets/amount field would not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This Azure policy will examine the subscription to determine if it has any budgets (Cost category) assigned to it. Please test it out and share your feedback.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "auditifNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
        "deploymentScope": "subscription",
        "existenceScope": "subscription",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets/category",
              "equals": "Cost"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```